# Android application support CDMA devices

Tags: android

I've created an facebook android app. Its works fine on GSM. When I run it on CDMA device, it didn't getting login even. I found this:

> "google stopped support for CDMA devices.Currently the app only
>   supports phones running on GSM networks. CDMA-network (for instance
>   Sprint and Verizon) phones and the Torch 9800 are not yet compatible."

ref:
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/02/07/google_android_cdma/

http://www.spotify.com/int/help/faq/mobile/

So can't I run my app on CDMA networks?

Comment: Is your CDMA phone running a custom build from AOSP? Because only those ROMs are affected, not official ROMs provided by carriers.

Comment: I dont have much idea about this topic.Lemme know whats diff bet official ROM & custom ROM?can u pls provide any link which covers this?

Comment: CDMA devices use an .apk signed by the platform key for their telephony. No surprise that individuals, and community ROMs developers do not have access to those keys, therefore those .apks may not work properly on a custom build from android open source porject.

Comment: How can i run my app on official ROMs?

Comment: how to sign apk file with platform key?

Comment: That's the reason I asked first question. If your phone is running an official ROM issued by carrier, you should have no problem running your application on it, but you may face problems if it's a custom build.

Comment: The quoted text has absolutely nothing to do with running an app on a CDMA or GSM device. Your app should work exactly the same on either, unless its using `telephony` classes. Please post the exception you get when the app is crashing.